# problem with RewriteRule and apache

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a SSL certificate that is registered to my www domain, but all my urls point to my domain without www.
i tried this sentence:

```
RewriteRule ^[https://mydomain.org](.*)$ https://www.mydomain.org$1 [R=301,nc]
```

but for some unknown reason, it also redirects all the calls made to http://mydomain.org as well. i realy cant think of a reason for this

Comment: [https://mydomain.org] is a character class, i.e. all these characters will match: h,t,p,s,m,y,d,o,m,a,i,n,r,g, colon, slash, dot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

But the invalid certificate message won’t go away since the SSL connection is accomplished before HTTP is taking part (since HTTPS is HTTP over SSL/TSL).

Answer (score 1):

Someone should correct me if i'm wrong but i don't think the RewriteRule directive has access to the protocol part of the requested uri. Try this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^https://domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: now it doesn't do any redirects what so ever (although i understand what you did and it seems it should work)

Answer (score 0):

How about detecting the server port?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R]
```

so litterally, if you are connecting to https (since you are using port 443) the url will have WWW.